# static Math.random change java

Tags: java, random, static, non-static

I don't have a problem anymore, However I want to understand the behaviour of some code. Initially I was generating some random numbers and somewhere in my code the Math.random was returning the same number for all iterations. I tried to create a minimal example with the following two Classes:

first Class:

```
public class randomTest {   


 public randomTest()
    {    }
    public double generateRandomNumber()
    {
        double r = Math.random();
        return r;
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        randomTest t = new randomTest();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            System.out.println(t.generateRandomNumber());
    }    
}
```

The second class:

```
public class anotherClass {
    private randomTest t = new randomTest();

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            anotherClass c = new anotherClass();
            System.out.println(c.t.generateRandomNumber());
        }

    }
}
```

I was trying to generate a minimal code example to track the reason why I am always getting the same random value for the whole 10 iterations. In this minimal example the results are correct and random, However In my real situation The output of the second class is the same for the whole ten iterations.

At last i was able to solve the problem by changing the method I am calling into a static method. I still don't understand how did this solve my problem, and where the original problem was.

Old Nonworking code:

```
...
public ImagePlus createAnImage()
{
    drawBackground(c.ip);

    width = ip.getWidth();
    height =ip.getHeight();
    createCircles(requiredCircles); // this is not creating random numbers
    ArrayList<Circle> list = circlesList;
    drawBoundaries(list, ip, percentage);
    background.setProcessor(ip);

    return background;        
}
...
```

New Code:

```
...
public static ImagePlus createAnImage()
{
    createCircles c = new createCircles(); 
    c.drawBackground(c.ip);

    c.width = c.ip.getWidth();
    c.height =c.ip.getHeight();
    c.createCircles(c.requiredCircles); // this is creating random numbers
    ArrayList<Circle> list = c.circlesList;
    c.drawBoundaries(list, c.ip, c.percentage);
    c.background.setProcessor(c.ip);

    return c.background;        
}
...
```

In both cases I was already creating an instance of createCircles class from another class as follows:

```
...
private ImagePlus createRandomImage(int radius, int numberOfCircles, double minPercentage,   double maxPercentage, int minBackground, int maxBackground)
{
    // create the image using class createCircles
    createCircles c = new createCircles();
    c.setParameters(radius, radius, minBackground, maxBackground, numberOfCircles, imageWidth, imageHeight, minPercentage, maxPercentage);
    ImagePlus imp = c.createAnImage(); // calling the static method works

    return imp;               
}
```

Although my problem is solved, I still need to understand the reason behind this. I suppose a better understanding of static vs. non-static methods might explain it. Anyone has a clue?

Best Regards,
M. Tleis

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Math.[random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) (it produces doubles, not integers)

use the [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class to generate random integers between 0 and N.

> To generate a series of random numbers as a unit, you need to use a single Random object - do not create a new Random object for each new random number.

```
import java.util.Random;

/** Generate 10 random integers in the range 0..99. */
public final class RandomInteger {

  public static final void main(String... aArgs){
    log("Generating 10 random integers in range 0..99.");

    //note a single Random object is reused here
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    for (int idx = 1; idx <= 10; ++idx){
      int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
      log("Generated : " + randomInt);
    }

    log("Done.");
  }

  private static void log(String aMessage){
    System.out.println(aMessage);
  }
}
```